# build loopback where query dynamicaly

Tags: mongodb, where-clause, loopback

I'm trying to build the following query object dynamically

This code works with the hard coded object and returns data

```
var query = {where: {or: [{field1: /franklin/i}, {field2: /franklin/i}]}}
myMongoLoopbackModel.find(query,
     function(err, response) {
     if (err) cb(new Error('Something went wrong!'));
      cb(null, response);
   });
```

The query is trying to search mongodb, via the loopback api, where either field1 or field2 contain the string "franklin", and that string is provided by user input.

Here is the dynamic code that is not working.

```
var userinput= new RegExp(userform.inputvalue,'i');
var query= {where: []};
query['where'].push({or: [
    {field1: userinput},
    {field2: userinput}

 ]});
 myMongoLoopbackModel.find(query,
     function(err, response) {
     if (err) cb(new Error('Something went wrong!'));
      cb(null, response);
   });
```

When I console log the first, working, query i get:

```
log working:  { where: { or: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

When I console log the second, non-working, query, I get:

```
log non-working: { where: [ { or: [Array] } ] }
```

I have researched other, similar, posts and derived my approach from this one.
[How to dynamically build MongoDB Query with multiple OR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45068245/how-to-dynamically-build-mongodb-query-with-multiple-or)

I would appreciate any help you can provide.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` clause should not be an array. Rewriting your code:

```
var userinput= new RegExp(userform.inputvalue,'i');
var query = {where: {or: [{field1: userinput}, {field2: userinput}]}}
myMongoLoopbackModel.find(query,
 function(err, response) {
 if (err) cb(new Error('Something went wrong!'));
  cb(null, response);
});
```

Comment: Have a follow up question. To elaborate further, I have multiple input fields, which, if there is data in them, need to be included in the query. So, how do I add other "and" conditions if the "where" is not an array?

Comment: You can have a blank placeholder and populate it whenever required. `var query = {where: {or: [{field1: userinput}, {field2: userinput}], and: []}}` and then `query['where']['and'].push({field3: userinput2})`

Comment: Ok. While using the blank place holder, I was able to populate the "and" using  this: query['and'].push({field3: userinput2}) , however; the query doesn't work. The actual format that works is:

Comment: sorry. didn't edit the above in time. Here is what I was trying to say:   Ok. While using the blank place holder, I was able to populate the "and" using  this: query['and'].push({field3: userinput2}) , (note the ['where']['and'] didnt work) , however; the query doesn't return data. The actual format that works is: query = {where: {and: [{or: [{field1: userinput},  {field2: userinput}]}, {field3: userinput2}]}};   Except, when I try query['and'].push({field3: userinput2})  I get : "Cannot read property 'push' of undefined" Any further help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you try `query['where']['and'].push({field3: userinput2})` now? I think, it should work.

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much!